# C++ - How to read from a file that has lines that have to be ignored

Tags: c++, properties, streamreader, ifstream

I have searched anywhere I could to find such thing, believe it or not, for around 3 months...

And it also came to my mind that this is probably something incredibly easy...But after experimenting lots of times, I had no success.

It might be possible to find this somewhere else, but I'm also not sure how to search for it, that's why I'm asking here.

So here's what I want to do:
I have a file like this

### [Property]

1 Din 17 M 10 D FFF

2 Dout 12 F 11 F FFF

### [Names]

1 Din

2 Dout

**The file ends here.**

I want to read the whole file into variables, which I already do, for example:

```
std::ifstream readP("properties.dat");    

unsigned short ID;
std::string Name;
unsigned short p2;
char p3;
unsigned short p4;
char gTemp;
std::string fProperty;

while(readP >> ID >> Name >> p2 >> p3 >> p4 >> gTemp >> fProperty);
```

Now I want to read everything, except the [Property] and the [Names], because obviously with these fields in the text, the reader will not read, because they aren't being read from the while loop.

What would be a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You must do a bit more elaborate parsing.

So, try this:

- Read a line.
- Decide how to process it.

  - A) Skip.
  - B) Parse into variables.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "ignore" lines, but you could "skip" them.

I would suggest reading sequentially line by line with [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) then skip the uninteresting stuff.

Notice that lines don't really exist in most file systems (at least Posix ones). Lines are just conventionally terminated by `\n` but a file is a sequence of bytes.

Comment: Lines exist. There are only different definitions, using e.g. fixed length or a terminator or a separator. Different systems do not neccessarily concurr on the separators / terminators.

Comment: I wrote that "lines don't exist in *file systems*"

Answer (score 0):

You should read line by line, and the determin whether you are going to process this line.

You can check if the first character is `[` or not.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/

```
if (str.at(0) != '[')
{
//Process this line by splitting the string with space ect
}
```